# \pagebreak affects top of next page

Tags: spacing, page-breaking

Why does a \pagebreak push the heading at the top of the next page down? To match other pages, I need to add \vspace*{-3\baselineskip} after the page break.[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{32pt}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-4em}
\lhead{-}
\rhead{-}

\renewcommand\thesection{A-\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection-\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection \ \alph{subsubsection})}

\begin{document}

\subsection{}
\pagebreak
\subsection{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you please add a Minimal Working Example (that is, a complete source file, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) that illustrates the problem you are reporting?

Comment: BTW, the showframe package helps.  For normal text,  \includegraphics or \rule I don't see any difference.

Comment: Also, I HAVE noticed that the first page of a document requires \vspace*{-11.05532074pt} in order to show a full page graphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `\pagebreak`, but `fancyhdr`.

If you look at the warnings in the log file, you'll see

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (0.0pt): 
 Make it at least 12.0pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

This explains the fact that the second page is moved 12pt down. Comply with the recommendation and you'll not have the problem.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the error extend past 'Package Fancyhdr Warning: headheight is too small (0.0pt): Make it at least 12.0pt.'

Do you know how to turn this off?